# Invalid syntax python 3.7 turtle game

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
#boundary Checking
    if goals[count].ycor() > 240 or goals[count].ycor() < -240:
        goals[count].right(180)


        #collision checking
    if isCollision(player, goals[count]):
        goals[count].setposition(random.randint(-250, 250), random.randint(-250, 250))
        goals[count].right(random.randint(0,360))
        score += 1
        #Drwa the score on the screen
        mypen.undo()
        mypen.penup()
        mypen.hideturtle()
        mypen.setposition(-240, )
        scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
        mypen.write(scorestring, False, align="left", font=("Arial",14, "normal")

delay = raw_input("press Enter to Finish")
```

Comment: Could you post more details? Actual error message would be helpful.

Comment: When you get an error message you generally need to include it in your question, starting from the `Traceback` line, so that readers can tell what part of the program is causing the problem. But in this case it's obvious: the `raw_input` function has been renamed to `input` in Python 3 (and the old `input` function has been discarded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit lacking in details but off the bat I can already see a potential problem. The `raw_input()` function in Python 2 and earlier was renamed to `input()` in Python 3